# undefined method `visit' for []:Array in RSpec 3 feature tests in 2019

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to get this most simple of feature test to run.
With RSpec 3 Syntax, ruby-2.5.1, rails 5 as used in 2019:

```
RSpec.feature "Roots", type: :feature do
  fixtures :page_model
  fixtures :event
  fixtures :level
  fixtures :phase

  it "loads the homepage" do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_content 'Team'
  end

  it "loads a page" do
    p = page(:page2)
    puts p.name
    visit page_path(p)
    expect(page).to have_content p.body
  end
end
```

But I always get an error

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `visit' for []:Array
 # /Users/someuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@rails5/gems/capybara-3.16.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
 # ./spec/features/root_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Note that the error occurse at the line

```
visit root_path
```

which has nothing to do with pages at all.

I've narrowed it down to the first fixture file:  if I comment it out

```
RSpec.feature "Roots", type: :feature do
  # fixtures :page
  fixtures :event
  fixtures :level
  fixtures :phase

  it "loads the homepage" do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_content 'Team'
  end
end
```

then the test runs without error and succeeds.  But I can't find a problem
with the fixture file:

```
page1:
  id: 1
  cached_slug: info
  name: "Information"
  body: "this and that"
  created_at: "2011-03-01 10:09:53"
  updated_at: "2016-07-21 12:15:46"
  visibility: visibility_public

page2:
  id: 2
  cached_slug: impressum
  name: "Impressum + Kontakt"
  body: "dies ist ein Projekt"
  created_at: "2011-03-01 10:09:53"
  updated_at: "2016-12-05 10:42:30"
  visibility: visibility_public
```

Comment: Hmm, it may not be related, but the only thing I see it on the first fixture is that the body is not closing the p tag `"<p>this and that"`

Comment: According to your fixture file, wouldn't the yml define page as an array of pages? What if you did 'visit page[0]'?

Answer (score 0):

The fixture cannot be called page.yml, because that creates
a method `page()` for loading from fixture. This overrides the `page` 
that is implicitly set by `visit`: the object representing the page
that was just loaded.

I had to change the filename of the fixture-file to `page_model.yml`, and
load that instead:

```
RSpec.feature "Roots", type: :feature do
  fixtures :page_model
  fixtures :event
  fixtures :level
  fixtures :phase

  it "loads the homepage" do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_content 'Team'
  end

  it "loads a page" do
    p = page_model(:page1)
    puts p.name
    visit page_path(p)
    expect(page).to have_content p.body
  end
end
```

Notice that now i can use `page_model(:page1)` to load a fixture.

In [Set model name in fixtures as metadata](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/08/09/set-model-name-in-fixtures-as-metadata.html#the-rails-5-way) I learned that 
you can specify the class of the model in the fixture file:

```
_fixture:
  model_class: Page

page1:
  id: 1
  cached_slug: info
  name: "Information"
  body: "this and that"
  created_at: "2011-03-01 10:09:53"
  updated_at: "2016-07-21 12:15:46"
  visibility: visibility_public

page2:
  id: 2
  cached_slug: impressum
  name: "Impressum + Kontakt"
  body: "dies ist ein Projekt"
  created_at: "2011-03-01 10:09:53"
  updated_at: "2016-12-05 10:42:30"
  visibility: visibility_public
```